# How to attach a block device to qemu VM through qemu command line?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, qemu, block-device

I want to configure the qemu to attach a specific block device to the VM?

Following is the command I am using now:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -machine type=pc,accel=kvm 
                   -cpu host -nographic  -k de -usb -m 2048 
                   -net nic -net user,hostfwd=tcp::3388-:22
                    ubuntu16.04.qcow2
```

I know that following is the virsh command to do this:

```
virsh attach-disk ubuntuVM /dev/vdb
```

But I want to specify this in the above command line (Don't want to use virsh). Does anyone know how to do this?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 9):

Simply add the following option to your command:

```
-drive file=/dev/sdd,format=raw,if=virtio
```

This will add a drive, the **file** parameter can also point to block devices, be sure to set the **format** parameter to "*raw*".

Additionally you can set the **if** parameter to "*virtio*" if the guest supports it (via module or driver) for better performance.